# Use oauth with Volley or Retrofit

Tags: java, android, oauth, android-volley, retrofit

I am trying to get the dashboard posts of the user from Tumblr using Volley. I tried Jumblr(Tumblr API for Java) but it didn't meet my needs.
Below is my code. Please help me accomplish this. If you can do this with Retrofit or without Retrofit and Volley, it is still great. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
 String url = "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/dashboard";

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        Log.d("com.waheed",response.toString());

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            headers.put("Authorization", "oauth_consumer_key=\"cMlaBmZqDcoOEYfzSdYAXg1kOw1BrE5VyAVa2G3OC56KEwUhrW\",oauth_token=\"o7qRQuKK3vuRvGeywmXW8XzqvofsMzxKGY0CEchyOSq83jIWcZ\"");
            return headers;
        }
    };

    mQueue.add(request);
```

Comment: [This](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/oauth-2-on-android-with-retrofit) might help you

Comment: Thanks, @AbdulKawee. I'll try it. But I am already trying the same approach with Volley.